# Secure Badges on Site?

Tags: security, security-certificate

I have a new client whose site I will be re-building. I noticed on his site he has a badge from McAfee saying the site is secure. Below is an example:

[image: Example Badge]

I have seen similar type badges by other companies as well on other sites.

My question is this:

Do these types of services increase conversion and trust for a site? In other words, these services claim that it will increase the trust for the consumer thus increase sales and interactions on your website.

I am looking for studies that provide proof or results than just an opinion as an answer, preferably by a third party who does not offer the service.

*Edit*

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/359/9539) is essentially the same but the answer there provide opinions vs documented studies (other than the ones the companies provide). I am looking for documented studies as an answer.

Comment: This is a truly interesting question! I am interested too. I do not recall any studies other than what the various companies offer. I know that I do look at these badges. Some are serious about their work. Some not so much. It is also the perceived reputation of the company behind the badge at work. As well, it is not just the badge, but the page the badge may link to. I would suspect that there is an effect- but what that effect is exactly, I cannot tell you. If I were selling online, I would want some of the top badges. I would not take any chances. ;-) Perhaps that is how they make money.

Comment: If you add a bounty to the other question you *may* get better answers

Comment: @JohnConde - Done. Hopefully, I will receive some better answers. =>